# Javascript : Convert HH:MM:SS:FF timecode to seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, adobe

Am trying to convert HH: MM:SS:FF to seconds, since my calculation giving one frame backward, following is my calculation

```
function convertToSec (hms) {
        var framerate= 29.97;
        var a = hms.split(":"); // split it at the colons
        var dropFrame= true;

      // combine hours and minutes into minutes
        var minutes = (a[0] * 60) + Number(a[1]);
        // now that we have the total number of minutes, subtract how many minutes are divisible by ten
        var minutesCounted = minutes - Math.floor(minutes / 10);
        // combine mintues and seconds to seconds
        var seconds = (minutes * 60) + Number(a[2]);
        var frames = Number(a[3]);
        // fractions of frames? no. round up though.
        frames += Math.ceil(seconds * framerate);
        // only run if we're dealing with dropFrame timecode
        if (dropFrame) {
          // we don't subtract 2 if we're on frame 0 or 1 of the first minute so let's add one or two frames back in
          if (a[3] < 2 && minutesCounted > 0 && a[2] == '00') {
            // 1 frame if we're on '01' and 2 if we're on '00'
            frames += (2 - Number(a[3]));
          }
          // from the minutes counted above, we'll subtract 2 frames per minute
          frames = frames - (minutesCounted * 2);
        }
        // convert frames back into seconds and multiply by (1001 / 1000)
        return parseFloat(parseFloat(frames / framerate) * 1.001);

    }
```

Example:
convertToSec(00:00:02:06);
//result 2.2044044044044044
The result is almost correct, However, When I input this to a video player as startTime it seems one Frame bakward in the result, Please can anyone help me on this?